# Is it possible to share users between 2 or more tenants in Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

wanted to know how to make the following scenario happen. 
2 or more companies are cooperating and trusting each other. I need to make it so that each company manages its own users but the others can see them. Like shared users. I think the proper way to do it is to look at each company as a different Azure AD Tenant. The users that the company adds are guest users but the companies itself need to have an Azure AD account (They are tenants after all).

Is it something that is possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the user's as guests in the other tenants. This will require invitation and accepting the invite of course per user/per tenant.

Alternatively you can build a custom app that gets users in each tenant and displays them in ways you require. 
You can achieve this with a multi-tenant app that requires app-level access to users. 
You'd need to consent it to the other tenants so it can access them.